# The transparent button showing an image

Tags: android, c++, qt

I want to create a button that displays a given image with a transparent background. I am using the code segment below:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setFixedSize(width, height);

QPixmap* orgPixmap = new QPixmap(":/images/a.png");
QSize size(this->width(), this->height());
QPixmap resizePixmap(orgPixmap->scaled(size));

QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(resizePixmap));
this->setPalette(palette);

ui->toolButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");
ui->toolButton->setFixedSize(64, 64);
ui->toolButton->setIconSize(QSize(64, 64));
ui->toolButton->setIcon( QIcon(":/images/add.png") );
```

At the top of the widget, I have added a button with an icon. This is a blue circle with a transparent background. However, when I deploy and run my code on an Android device, the button is displayed with an opaque background with white colour.

Please see the picture:

[image]

I have tried to force the transparency for the button using the following code:

```
QColor transparent_color(0,0,0,0);
QPalette button_palette(ui->pushButton->palette());

button_palette.setColor(QPalette::Button, transparent_color);
ui->toolButton->setPalette(button_palette);
```

The above code did not seem to have the desired effect as I had expected.
I would like to know what the problem might be and how to fix it.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. You want the transparent widget on top  of the other widget and only showing the image?

Comment: Sorry for my English skill is not good. But the thing you said which is i want

Comment: Have you checked `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);` on the button?

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673983/how-to-put-png-image-with-transparent-background-in-qtoolbutton

Comment: I have tried "ui->toolButton->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);" but it still not work as i want

Comment: Are you tried set `Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground` (with `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`) to true also?

Answer (score 0):

I see you need a circular button, so how about `QWidget::setMask()`?

```
QPainterPath path;
path.addEllipse(ui->pushButton->rect());
QRegion mask = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
ui->pushButton->setMask(mask);
```

Just an idea, I did not test that.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a simple style sheet. Like so: `widget->setStyleSheet(rgba(255, 255, 255,0);");` if you want to adjust the opacity, just change the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have recenyly resolved similar problem on a Win/Mac project based on Qt Graphics View Framework, pls note I never tested this on Android platform.

Anyhow, first you need to setForegroundBrush() for your  Graphics Scene:

```
ui.yourGraphicsView->scene()->setsetForegroundBrush(Qt::transparent);
```

Alternatively you may use Qt Designer to get similar result or edit your Project.ui file as follows:

```
<widget class="QGraphicsView" name="yourGraphicsView">
...
 <property name="foregroundBrush">
  <brush brushstyle="NoBrush">
   <color alpha="255">
    <red>0</red>
    <green>0</green>
    <blue>0</blue>
   </color>
  </brush>
 </property>
```

And now setBackgroundBrush() as transparent for your button:

```
ui->toolButton->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::transparent);
```

I found these two to be sufficient to get hovering transparent button over other objects in QGraphicScene; calling `setMask()` is not required as Qt does it automatically for any QGraphicsPixmapItem (or ancestor) when it's set to alpha-channeled PNG. For buttons it also works as you would expect: clicking transparent area of your PNG (displayed white above) would NOT trigger OnClick() event, while clicking trnslucent parts on PNG-based button would.

Hope this helps...